# Do you need to manually level the bed with a BLTouch? Adhesion issues with Ender 5 and BLTouch 1.3

Tags: bed-leveling, adhesion, bltouch, creality-ender-5

I've just installed a BLTouch on my Ender 5 Pro and updated the firmware to 2.0.5.3 and enabled BL touch. I can send a `G29` which probes all the points correctly, I also get a readout of the results in OctoPrint terminal but when it puts a first layer down the filament does not adhere to the bed. I also end up with a large clump on filament stuck to my nozzle afterwards.

I've set the Z probe offset while the nozzle was in the center of the bed, and had a good grip on the piece of paper under it while setting it. I stored settings afterwards. I can't actually tell if the BL touch is even doing anything.

Do I need to manually level the bed before using the printer with a BLTouch? It currently has not been leveled since I assembled the printer. I guessed the BLTouch would handle this for me and I wouldn't need to level the bed ever?

These were the results from my `G29`:

```
-0.218, -0.148, -0.116, -0.088, -0.084
-0.194, -0.136, -0.115, -0.061, -0.020
-0.138, -0.035, +0.030, +0.091, +0.107
-0.008, +0.062, +0.129, +0.191, +0.261
+0.160, +0.261, +0.339, +0.411, +0.469
```

Comment: Bed leveling it not magic, you still need to level the bed out as good as you can.

Answer (score 1):

### yes

Even with auto mesh bed leveling, you ought and should level the bed to a good degree to make the leveling not only more efficient: the mesh bed level is to work out small dimples and hills in the bed, bot to work with a crooked or heavily misaligned bed.